# How to use "export default { }" for component creation instead of "export default defineComponent({ })" in quasar v2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am facing this situation after upgrading from Quasar v1 to v2. I am used to use "export default", but now while I am creating new Vue apps using Quasar, predefined components like App.vue, MainLayout.vue and Index.vue are initialized with "export default defineComponent". I am not at all familiar with this structure. So, how can I initialize Vue 3 apps in Quasar V2 with components using "export default {}" structure. I am aware that they can be manually changed, but how to make them as default structure for further apps?

Comment: defineComponent is TS-friendly helper. The structure is the same as plain object. If you use TS, use defineComponent. If you don't, do not.

Comment: They are creating by default, though I am not selecting Typescript for installation. How to stop that default process. I am familiar with SFC structure.

Comment: defineComponent is TS friendly no-op function. See https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent . I didn't check but I suppose it also helps with VS Code because it uses TS internally even if the project doesn't. The structure is the same as without it. It seems that you try to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @EstusFlask You don't understand. I am trying to create new Quasar app. And by default the components are defined with "defineCompoent" function. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can't comment why this is by default in Quasar regardless of whether TS is in use but I strongly suspect defineComponent is there to improve IDE experience, VSC in particular.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yeah, may be due to VSC. I used to experience unnecessary code error red indicators while using props and emit properties. Anyway. thank you for the clarification. I never used defineComponent, maybe this is the time to get used to it.